# Draw phase diagram of $x'' + V(x) = 0$ conservative system, with $V(x) = \omega^2 \cos{x} - \alpha x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to draw the phase diagram of $x'' + V(x) = 0$, with $V(x) = \omega^2 \cos{x} - \alpha x$, 
with all constants greater than $0$.

I write this second order differential equation as a system in this way:

$$ x' = y $$
$$ y' = \omega^2 \cos{x} - \alpha x $$

Then I linearize the second equation finding:
$$ y = \omega^2 x + \alpha $$

The equilibrium point is $(-\frac{\alpha}{\omega^2},0)$
I then find the matrix A:\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1  \\
    \omega^2  & 0  
\end{bmatrix}

The eigenvalues are w and -w, so I find that the equilibrium point is unstable because I have an Eigen value with real part positive.

Is this procedure right?

From now on I am stuck, because I do not know how to draw the phase diagram.

Comment: **Hint** Plot level sets of $\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2} + \int_{0}^{x} V(z)\, dz$. All trajectories lie on level sets of this first integral.

Comment: From what I understand that is the energy which is constant for a conservative system. However I am not sure how follow up on that.

Comment: How to follow up on what exactly? You can just differentiate this function by $t$ and see for yourself that derivative vanishes, hence this system is conservative. Did you try to plot level sets of the first integral? Try ones that go through equilibria first.